# how to translate variable to other language

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to translate my app into different languages.Work fine on text widget but not working when a variable comes with a TEXT widget

```
date == null
    ? Text(
        'Expected_Date'.tr,
      )
    : Text(
        'Expected_Date = $dueDate'.tr,
      ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change variable to this :

```
Text(
  '${'Expected_Date'.tr} = $dueDate'
)
```

Comment: how to translate my calendar.?